# I need to get a folder by metadata in Power Automate (Flow)

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow, power-automate

I am new to Flow but I am a c# programmer. I'm just trying to get around the syntax of how flow works.

1 - I have a process that runs that returns an email address.

2 - I want to compare the found email address with email address metadata I have on a SharePoint document folder.

Sounds pretty simple but I don't know the proper syntax for it.

I am just not sure how to query for the email address from SharePoint efficiently. I have a hard coded test working but need some advice on how to query a list of folders for metadata and only retrieve the matching result.

**See below.** I think what I am trying is overkill. I am getting a folder list. Then for each item I am trying to compare the properties. I am guessing there has to be a simpler way (a Method) to query the item.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m not quite sure what your requirement is. There is no specific action for comparing properties, the comparing process is usually used as a **Filter** to get the items you need for the next action.

Or you can use the comparison in **Condition** Control directly to filter the items/files you need to take actions on.

Here’s an example:

[image]

Here are some posts which might give you some idea on how to build the flow:

[Microsoft Flow: Get files (properties only) of file only in a specific folder.](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Microsoft-Flow-Get-files-properties-only-of-file-only-in-a/td-p/180332)

[Get Files (Properties Only) - Look in Sub Folder Only.](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Get-Files-Properties-Only-Look-in-Sub-Folder-Only/td-p/294046)

Comment: This looks to be what I need. Thanks.